# Multiple share buttons that produce different content, within the same page, using Facebook OpenGraph Meta tags

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, meta

I have a "single page" website. Let's call it "mySite.com/index.html".

There are several different places on my page that I would like users to  share via Facebook. Each of these items should display a different image and headline text, when shared on the user's Facebook timeline.

Each of these item posts should link Facebook users back to my website, "mySite.com/index.html", when the posts are viewed from a Facebook timeline.

Example:

On my page, I wish to have two different share buttons:

A. ButtonA: This button would create a picture of an elephant on the user's Facebook timeline, with the headline, "A Beautiful Elephant!". This post on the user's timeline should link back to my page, when the post is clicked.

A. ButtonB: This button would create a picture of a tiger on the user's Facebook timeline, with the headline, "A Scary Tiger!". This post on the user's timeline should link back to my page, when the post is clicked.

The Problem:

My understanding is that in order to create Facebook timeline posts which contain attractive headline text and images, I must use Facebook OpenGraph Meta tags, on the same page that is being linked to. It seems impossible to have two different sets of Facebook meta tags on "mySite.com/index.html", one outlining the 'elephant' post, and the other outlining the 'tiger' post.

The only possible solution I can think of is this:

- Create a special 'Facebook Meta HTML Page' for each post I want to make. Each 'special page would only contain the meta tags for the post I wish to outline. "mySite.com/elephant_meta.html"

The body of the special page would be blank. This will work, but there is a problem: The resulting Facebook post will link users to "mySite.com/elephant_meta.html", which is just a blank page. I wish them to be directed to "mySite.com/index.html".

Solution: Create a JavaScript redirect in the body of "mySite.com/elephant_meta.html". This redirect will take users to "mySite.com/index.html".

This will work, but it feels incredibly hacky. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still finding my way on the open graph stuff as well, but the way I understand it, you can set og:url to the url that you want users to go to when they click on the link in your story on facebook.  So each of your meta pages could point back to your main site page using the og:url meta tag.